# Website ban crawler after crawl some links

Tags: session, scrapy, web-crawler

I am having a problem with scrapy.
When I using scrapy spider to access a website. After 20-30 minutes, website prevent my crawler. Scrapy always return 500 code. (DELAY_TIME = 10s)

But if I stop scrapy and start it immediately. It can crawl normally. I think this website prevent a session can be view a number of page?

How can I change session of scrapy when it run? Or resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there can be a variety of ways to tackle this saturation.

first of all you should Review robots.txt file that will be placed on **`root`** of the website. to insure that Scraping is allowed on this website or not.

they try `COOKIES_ENABLED=False` in your settings only if website allowed you to disable cookies. most of websites track your activities using cookies.

Comment: Thanks. I used setting ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True. I will try with COOKIES_ENABLED=False but why I can't find this setting at http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html

Comment: yes they should add this in settings , but un fortunately  its in FAQ
https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=COOKIES_ENABLED